# Filtering Observable array elements from another Observable array

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I had an issue to filter an observable array, in my case it's `resources$` (an observable which contains all 'resourses' as JSON), and I have another observable called `usedResources$`, what I want to achieve is simply get `unusedResources$` from those 2 variables **(resources - usedResources = unusedResources)**, is there any RxJS way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple streams and you want to combine each item from them somehow, usually that means either `combineLatest` or `zip` depending on your desired combination strategy.

#### combineLatest | [documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest)

If you want to compute the latest from the most recent item from each stream, regardless of how fast or slow they emit relative to eachother, you would use `combineLatest`; either `Observable.combineLatest` or the prototype based `stream$.combineLatest` which has the same effect but includes the stream you call it on instead of being a static factory. I personally use the static form more often for clarity.

This is probably what you want.

```
const unusedResources$ = Observable.combineLatest(
  resources$,
  usedResources$,
  (resources, usedResources) => ({
    something: resources.something - usedResources.something
  })
);
```

```js
const { Observable } = Rx;

const resources$ = Observable.interval(5000).map(i => ({
  something: (i + 1) * 1000
}));

const usedResources$ = Observable.interval(1000).map(i => ({
  something: (i + 1) * 10
}));

const unusedResources$ = Observable.combineLatest(
  resources$,
  usedResources$,
  (resources, usedResources) => ({
    something: resources.something - usedResources.something
  })
);

unusedResources$.subscribe(
  unusedResources => console.log(unusedResources)
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.4.0/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

---

#### zip | [documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-zip)

If you instead want to combine each item 1:1 i.e. waiting for every stream to emit an item for a given index, you can use `zip`. However, under the hood it uses an unbounded buffer, so if your streams don't emit at around the same interval you can potentially balloon your memory usage or even run out entirely. For the most part, this should only be used for streams which have a finite, predictable count and interval. For example, if you made N number of ajax calls and want to combine the results of them 1:1.